# Integration testing IdentityServer4 repository

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am using the repository pattern within my implementation, and adding an ApiResourceRepository.  Here is a sample of that:

```
public class ApiResourceRepository : IApiResourceRepository
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public ApiResourceRepository(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _dbSettings = dbSettings;
    }

    public async Task<ApiResource> Get(int id)
    {
        ApiResource result;

        using (var serviceScope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConfigurationDbContext>();
            result = await
                context.ApiResources
                .Include(x => x.Scopes)
                .Include(x => x.UserClaims)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Is this the suggested way of obtaining/working with a `ConfigurationDbContext`?

I am also struggling with my integration tests, because it seems like I would have to mock an IServiceProvider that can provide an instance of the `ConfigurationDbContext`?  How do you address these concerns?

Comment: Why are you not taking the ComfigurationDbContext as a constructor argument?

Comment: Because I would like a new context for every unit of work, and because this is a repository, multiple operations could be called that would dirty up the context

Comment: Are you high? `DbContext` is registered as a scoped service so a new one is created per ASP.Net request. And why would it matter if they were "dirtied" you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist and which you have come up with yourself.